# Passing list for InsertProvider mybatis-annotation - Illegal argument exception

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to insert multiple rows with mybatis. I got huge help w.r.t xml mapping. I want to do it with mybatis annotations.
So i used Insertprovider and passed the list. i am getting illegal argument exception...
Code below

```
@InsertProvider(type=SqlHelper.class,method="insertList")
public void addCartItemList(List<CartItem> list);

public class SqlHelper {
public String insertList(List<CartItem> list){}}
```

Am not sure why am getting illegal argument exception ,as i am sending arguments of same type.
Is there any way to achieve this in annotation with out using Insertprovider?
If so , which is the best way to achieve (with annotations).
Thanks in advance.

Added Exception

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/context] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error invoking SqlProvider method (com.madad.grocery.apnabag.persistance.SqlHelper.insertList).  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Comment: Edit your post to include the complete stack trace, show enough of your code, and identify the statement that throws the exception. Otherwise the question will almost surely get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer.

```
public String insertList(List<CartItem> list){}}.
```

Though i am sending list, Mybatis expects the argument to be of type StrictMap.
So, i modified my code to

```
    public String insertList( Object list1){
    StrictMap map=(StrictMap) list1;
    List<CartItem> list=(List<CartItem>) map.get("collection");
  }
```

I got exception because it was not able to type cast directly. Thought, it might be useful to someone.